# Bootstrap 3 Carousel not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a carrousel with 7 images in it for a header of a website. However all the images just stack on top of one another. Here is my code, is there anything that I am doing wrong?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/signtraysandboxpansheader1170x300.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/builtupletterheader1170x300.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/flatcutlettersheader1170x300.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/ledilluminatedlettersheader1170x300.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/header1170x450.png">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/totems&monolithheader1170x300.png">
                </div>
                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You've included all the [relevant bootstrap-related css and javascript files](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/), right?

Comment: Ive got bootstrap.min.css linked in the header and this at the end of the body:
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Also, you say you have 7 slides, but your code has 6 slides and 8 indicators. O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misplaced the ending `</div>` tag for `.carousel-inner`.  The carousel inner should contain all your `.item` elements.  Right now it only includes the first one.

http://www.bootply.com/q739Qe9Lvj